# Filter values by splitting string and get concatenated several values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am creating text-generation Excel spreadsheet.

I have a spreadsheet that **looks like this:**

```
0    1      2
A; text1; text2;
B; text3; text4;
C; text5; text6;
```

**What I need to achieve:**

```
Input: str(A,B) with index 1
Output: text1text3 (concatenated / joined strings)
```

I've tried VLOOKUP and FILTER `=FILTER(Data!B3:C10, SPLIT(C5, ",")=Data!A3:A10)` however it does not work and requires one row `(FILTER RANGE REQUIRES SINGLE COLUMN OR ROW)`

Error message:
[image]

Comment: what version of excel are you using that has the `split` function?

Comment: where are you getting your input and index from? Is it always 2 inputs? If yes, then you should be able to use two `VLOOKUP` with the `&` to concatenate the two lookups

Comment: I am using dropdown function in the Google Sheets with custom script that allows multiple choices. So, if you choice A, B it will be "A,B"; if you choice A,B,C it will be "A,B,C"

Comment: Concatenation of two VLOOKUP will not work because there is no fixed (hardcoded) possibility. There can be 1) A 2) B,C 3) A,B,C and etc. Ulimited combinations. That's the problem.

Comment: convert a custom script to excel formulas? sounds like a tall order. How do you select which index? How is the index determined? There may be a way but will require adding a helper column.

Comment: Data!B3:C10 the problem array?

Comment: You mention Excel in your question and Google sheets in your comment to @gns100.   Also you have your columns numbered and your rows with letters (inverse of what is typical in both apps)  You provide formulas without any cells that match the coordinates (C10?).   It is a bit confusing what is actually going on.  Maybe take another stab at the question if you want help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot that I can't ask about as I can't make Comments, but here's a basic approach:

```
=CONCAT(  VLOOKUP(  FILTERXML("<group><element>" & SUBSTITUTE(E2, ",", "</element><element>") & "</element></group>","/*/*"), A1:C4, MATCH(F2,A1:C1,0), FALSE)  )
```

I assume the inputs to be in cells E2 and F2 with the shown table in A1:C4. I also assume the `;`'s are an artifact of trying to make a table in here for the question. If the `;`'s ARE intended, you just have to add string operations to the `FILTERXML()` to add them to the input pieces it will create by adding a `;` before the string in the `SUBSTITUTE()` and the string that closes the XML expression after the `SUBSTITUTE()` and string operations to remove them from the "textXXX" pieces returned by the `VLOOKUP()`. But they really look like artifacts so I took them out when writing the above.

The `FILTERXML()` trick is pretty old hat now and it basically pulls apart the input string (`str(A,B)`). There are LOTS of ways to do that thing, but the advantage of the `FILTERXML()` trick is that you do not have to deal with figuring out how to handle varying numbers of pieces in that string as it does it for you.

Placing it in `VLOOKUP()` means `VLOOKUP()` has one-to-two-to-however-many-inputs to the lookup value parameter. Means it will look for all of them, and you don't have to allow for figuring out how many to provide for. *However,* since `VLOOKUP()` will only take ONE input that resolves to an "array constant" (in this example, `FILTERXML()` creates the array constant of `{"A";"B"}`), the second input (the `1` in this example) CANNOT also be something that creates multiple inputs.

To be harsher, it won't result in an error... Excel just ignores the idea of it taking only the first element of such a return and gives you that result. So you might not notice for quite a while that the formula is indeed failing. But since you ask using inputs that are only multiple for the lookup values in column A, it's A-OK. But not extensible the way you might think.

You also need not be concerned with whether the lookup array is created as a column (`{"A";"B"}` — notice the `;` separating them... if it had created a row for the return it would be `{"A","B"}` with a `,` separating the elements) or as a row because you are going to have only a one row/column vector returned and joining them will return the elements as a single item either way. Nice to not have as a detail to provide for.

I then used `CONCAT()` to join them as it is very simple in this use. Usually I would go to `TEXTJOIN()` but why add extra stuff when `CONCAT()` does the trick easily?

Notice the use of `MATCH()` using the second input to search for the column in the data range that it matches. By starting with A1 instead of, say, B1, the value it returns will match the "Xth" number column in the data range, just as `VLOOKUP()` demands, on its own, so no adding a `+1` or the like to it as it gets it directly. That seems obvious here, as your index numbering starts in column A, but many tables like this would NOT, but rather would leave A1 blank and begin numbering in B1 for those index values. Starting in B1 would mean the return from `MATCH()` needs an adjustment (`+1` in this case) to return the right table column number so `VLOOKUP()` doesn't return the wrong column.

In this case, `MATCH()` (or `XMATCH()`) is perfect and gives exactly what you need perfectly. But in many cases it can be appropriate to use `HLOOKUP()` for the similar task those other cases require. It is not that the headers are numerical rather than text, just that you are feeding it to `VLOOKUP()` in a place that requires a simple number, not a formal column number (like `COLUMN()` would be used to find). Feed the return into a different function though and you might need to remember `HLOOKUP()`.

If you DID need to accommodate more than one value in the index input, it might be easier to force `INDEX()` into service here, though the `FILTERXML()` trick could be rejigged to have a second "Group/Element" level and could be made to yield a return of pairs that would then, themselves need separated before having the pieces, in whatever order, to join for the final result. Second and third XML groupings in it though take some thought crafting as they always depend upon the EXACT layout/sourcing of inputs, how the data is actually physically laid out, and how it must be formed together in the end.